# How to determine who wrote what to a socket, given 2 writers?

Tags: sockets

Say one part of a program writes some stuff to a socket and another part of the **same program** reads stuff from that same socket. If an external tool writes to that very same socket, how would I differentiate who wrote what to the socket (using the part that reads it)? Would using a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) work?

Comment: in case it matters, I use `C/C++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about TCP the situation you describe is impossible, because connections are 1-to-1. If you mean UDP, you can get the sender address by setting the appropriate flags in the recvmesg() function.